# POST not supported in custom Servlet as @Bean in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party servlet into my Spring Boot application and when I try to submit a POST to the servlet, I see the following in the logs:

```
PageNotFound: Request method 'POST' not supported
```

I've made a simple test that show this. I started using an [auto generated Spring Boot project](http://start.spring.io/). Then I created the following Servlet:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestServlet.class);
    
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doPost(req, resp); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        log.info("doPost was called!!");
    }
    
}
```

Then I my created Configuration like so:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {
    @Bean //exposes the TestServlet at /test
    public Servlet test() {
        return new TestServlet();
    }        
}
```

Then I run the application within Tomcat7.  I see in the logs:

```
ServletRegistrationBean: Mapping servlet: 'test' to [/test/]
```

Then I try to hit the endpoint with cUrl like so:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/test -data-binary '{"test":true}'
```

or

```
curl -XPOST -H'Content-type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/test -d '{"test":true}'
```

I've tried adding a @RequestMapping, but that didn't work either. Can anyone help me figure out how to support another Servlet inside my Spring Boot application?

You can find the sample application here: https://github.com/andrewserff/servlet-demo

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my previous experiences you have to call the servlet with a slash at the end (like `http://localhost:8080/test/`). If you don't put the slash at the end, the request is routed to the servlet mapped to `/`, which is by default the DispatcherServlet from Spring (your error message comes from that servlet).

Comment: After fixing the super.doPost, and trying it with the real test, it works with the trailing slash.  I feel like a dummy...it was a long late day!  ;)  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `TestServlet#doPost()` implementation calls the `super.doPost()` - which always sends a `40x` error (either `405` or `400` depending on the HTTP Protocol used).

Here's the implementation:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    String protocol = req.getProtocol();
    String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_post_not_supported");
    if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED, msg);
    } else {
        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, msg);
    }
}
```

A Servlet can be registered using two ways:
registering the Servlet as a Bean (your approach - which should be fine) or
using a `ServletRegistrationBean`:

```
@Configuration
public class ServletConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new TestServlet(), "/test/*");
    }
}
```

The slightly changed Servlet:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // super.doPost(req, resp);
        log.info("doPost was called!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: ah, you are correct which makes my test invalid!  haha.  However, I think that @dunni's answer was actually correct.  adding the trailing slash seems to work once I remove the super.doPost.